# encoding is lost or not encoded/decoded correct

Tags: java, spring, encoding, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Tool Suite and I got a REST server that I configured through one tutorial I found on Springs web site. Additionally I got a database that serves the requests from clients through the REST server. My problem is that the characters displayed in the browser are messed up. ☆Stars☆ becomes âStarsâ and so on. When I use an online [Character Encoder / Decoder](http://www.string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx) and encode with iso-8859-1 and decode it with utf-8 the result is what the characters are suppose to look like. I'm connecting to the server via AJAX using JSONP if that matters. It's like theres a step missing.

The tweaking I've done so far is this:

Beans.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?characterEncoding=latin1"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pa$$word"/>
</bean>
```

The `characterEncoding:latin1` made the text a bit more readable.

And I tried to put `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset:UTF-8">` in the heads of the html files without any success.

I got a PHP version of the services I'm building with the STS REST that displays everything as it's suppose to. So I don't think there's something wrong with the database and how it store the characters.

I'm clueless of what to try next.